# reposition popup window of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup that show in a specific place on a image, my objective is to detect the position of the element and check if is near of the end of the left or right browser side. Basically what is happening now  is the popup being overlaped/cut by the browser window.
I wish to detect when this is happening, and if is hapening in the left the popup go to the right, and vice-verse. Any suggestion how shold i do it?

Comment: Please, most questions like this had many down votes. but i hate to do that please post code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` to set the `left` property of the element to `50vw` half of vertical width of viewport minus half the `width` of the element, set `text-align` to `center`

```css
#popup {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">ABCD EF GHIJKLMN</div>
```